# What would it take to get the temperature of the human body to rise to 3,000 °F?

Tags: biology, super-powers, bio-mechanics, temperature, body-modification

I am creating a superhuman that can raise her overall body temperature to 3,000 °F (1648.889 °C) but I need to know the exact requirements of how that could happen.

Let's say this superhuman could regulate her body temperature emotionally. She is heat and shock resistant internally and externally. I've already decided that I want to implement her heart into this design. By raising her blood pressure to extremes she can produce heat.

However, that is not the only thing that can raise body heat nor can a body rely on this one function. If she could rely on this function what would the requirements be? Say her heart had extra chambers for heating and distributing blood or even a second heart... or could she even rely on heated blood alone? And if the heart option is even possible, how many BPMs would it take for her to reach 3,000 °F?

(this superhuman's powers are entirely genetic. She has genetic mutations so she is not a classic superhero... like a quirk if anyone knows what that is... this is not supposed to be a realistic superpower I just wish to know the possible requirements... she is not immune to overheating)

3,000 °F is her limit. She only needs to get to 400 °C to ignite an explosive known as potassium nitrate in her sweat. She also only needs to get to 400 °C briefly.

(I am ignoring fuel intake and physical immunity for now... there are other factors in her superpower but I am more focused on how she can raise her overall heat)

Comment: Have you done the calculations for how many *calories* this feat will require? I'm pretty sure the number is impractically large. Not to mention the [required secondary powers](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RequiredSecondaryPowers) of being so hot that her entire body will be either liquid or gas or busy combusting...

Comment: I had thought of the calories, yes, I did not calculate since it would be rather unrealistic as you've stated. That isn't necessarily what I'm going for in this particular instance. She would certainly have to have some sort of constant energy to make up for the calories if her body did not already have a genetic mutation to counter that. I did implement that she has a limit for how hot she can get and the span of how long she can create heat. The other possibility is that she'd have to consume large amounts of food to create the energy she needs...

Comment: The first requirement is for her body to be made of something other that proteins. Most proteins don't do all than well above 40 to 45 °C, and no protein survives above 120 °C. In fact, *iron* melts at 1538 °C (2800 °F)... Try tungsten? As a consequence of her body not being made of proteins, the meaning of the word "genetic" as applied to her is undefined.

Comment: Her body is not constantly at 3,000 °F which is her limit heat, she retains normal human temperatures unless she gets upset. In fact, the only reason why I want her to be able to reach said temperature is so she can set off an explosive in her sweat (potassium nitrate). Which I am now wondering could help with the energy intake dilemma but it is just an explosive... I should do some research on that particular matter...

Comment: @WhimsyDoesIt, my point was that obtaining that many calories is fairly unreasonable. You should probably state what additional issues you are ignoring, because otherwise you get smart-ass people (like me ) tearing apart your basic premise.

Comment: BTW, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_nitrate), "[KNO₃] can react explosively with reducing agents, but it is not explosive on its own". Unless you need heat, specifically, you may have better luck with something that is electrically detonated. I suspect biological electrical generation will be much easier than generating enough heat to liquefy (or worse) just about everything that makes up the human body.

Comment: You're right, I should. I'm more focused on bodily functions (metabolic rate, hormones, etc.) that could make this possible. I know that a normal human body could certainly not handle this amount of heat which is what I'm choosing to ignore. However, the fuel concept does bother me... I may research that later but for now I'm just trying to figure out a body function that could create this particular environment.

Comment: Suggested follow up question, how does the superhuman cool back down to a regular body temperature?

Comment: Good idea, a humorous solution would be plunging her into arctic waters.. (joking)

Comment: I would say it's impossible except by magic. So magic is the way to go. With out magic a human body would simply explode.

Comment: By magic then. The whole premise of superpowers is rather impossible I would say. Mine is just... incredibly far fetched.

Comment: Thermite can light someone on fire at 4,000 F.

Answer (score 1):

That's a tough one.

Assuming you still want her to be something resembling biology and her entire body needs to get above 3000 degrees, I think your best bet is to have her be made of 2D or 1D organic structures. Her skin could be something like graphene(made purely of carbon, with a melting point of over 3500 degrees), bones could be made of diamond and her tendons could be carbon nanotubes. The rest of her biology would have to be made of completely new materials, unfortunately, as there is no protein equivalent(that I know of) that doesn't denature well before 3,000 degrees.

If just her skin is that temperature, then she "just" needs heat shielding. Graphene could withstand the heat, but you'd need an insulating layer beneath that(maybe carbon aerogels) to prevent the rest of her body from cooking like an overburnt steak.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't going for full-body improvement and modification. I was more or less wondering what type of modifications could be made to the heart and excluding the fact that human flesh and bone burns under these extreme conditions. However, I think that using these materials for clothing or something to fit her would be interesting. I was more or less wondering which hormones and homeostasis would be affected and which bodily functions could be updated to create the heat in the first place. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @WhimsyDoesIt I looked at your question again and did a few calculations. If she derived the heat from the beating of her heart, then to generate the heat necessary to raise her body temp to 400°C her heart would have to beat 1.7 million times in one minute. This would burn around 25 million calories(assuming she weighed 130 pounds).

Comment: Thank you! This is much-needed information!

Comment: Maybe she can retain human organs by keeping them separated from the heat with incredible insulation --- like reflective vacuum pockets or something. Then she won't have to be completely robotic.